# Black Scholes Formula for Collar Option

Tags: black-scholes

I am wondering if there exists a Black Scholes pricing formula for a collar option?

Comment: @edouard Collar is Long Put , short call , long underlying.

Comment: @Geraldine - You need to break the collar down into Calls + Puts + Underlying Asset and price each. BS will give you price for calls and puts.

Comment: @Ash if you're confident about this, please elaborate in an answer...

Comment: @SRXX will do when I reach home. Not a good day at work so far

Comment: It looks like you already had an account here - if you'd like the two accounts merged, please use this form: http://quant.stackexchange.com/help/user-merge

Answer (score 4):

SRXX has talked about Intrest Rate Collar. Since it is not clear if you are looking for IR or equity here is my explaination of equity Collar

Equity Collar :-

- Structure 
  :- Buy Underlying Asset (e.g. Stock) and Buy an out of money put and write out of money call
- Payoff daigram
  [image]
- Replication  **COLLAR = long stock + long put (K1) + short call (K2)**

[image]

As you can see the Max gain / Loss is limited which the objective here

HTH

Comment: Arf yeah of course I made that assumption... I get what you meant now...

Comment: @is it possible for a collar equity option to have put and call options with different expirations?

Answer (score 3):

Your question lacks a bit of background to make sure that you are using the right terminology.

In short, you buy an interest rate **collar** to hedge exposure in rates when they get out of a zone. As you can see on the wiki [page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interest_rate_cap_and_floor) when you buy a collar, you essentially:

- Buy an interest rate cap with strike price $K_c$
- Sell an interest rate floor with strike price $K_f$

with the same underlying rate and maturity.

As a result, you make a profit when $r>K_c$ and and loss when $r<K_f$. Hence, if you have a short exposure to rates (i.e. you are willing them to go *down*, for example if you own a bond) then you are giving away any profit beyond $K_f$ and getting insurance against any loss beyond $K_c$.

So, the value of your collar is:

$$v_\text{collar}= v_\text{cap} - v_\text{floor}$$

You can price both the cap and the floor using Black's [formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black_model), and you get the value of the collar.

Note that you can take the exact same opposite position which is then called a **reverse collar**.